# Unable to load a image , (action blocked by cors policy) while i have set cross-origin to anonymous

Tags: javascript, html

So, i am getting started with machine learning in javascript, and i wanted to see an image classifier model in action.

so as i try to load the image in the browser it dosent work.

this is the error i get:

```
Access to image at 'file:///F:/rishit/ml5/imagerecognition/bird.png' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
```

this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>ML-5</title>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@0.4.3/dist/ml5.min.js"></script>

    </head>
<body>
    
<h1 style="text-align: center;" >Image classification</h1>
<img src="bird.png"
 alt="bird" id ="bird"   >
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

and this is my script.js

```
let img = document.getElementById('bird')
img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'

let classifier = ml5.imageClassifier('MobileNet',onLoad)

function onLoad(){
    console.log('yay!,its Done')
} 

classifier.classify(img).then(
    (results)=>{console.log(results)}
)
```

this is my file structure

bird.png  index.html  script.js

Comment: `ml` is not about machine learning, and question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are serving the image from the right folder? `Access to image at 'file:///F:/rishit/ml5/imagerecognition/bird.png'` **from origin 'null'.**

I don't think that you should add `img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'` or similar, most likely is something wrong with how you are serving your static files

Comment: the image file has no seperate folder it is in the parent directory only. if i remove to cross origin it still throws a error :DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': The image element contains cross-origin data, and may not be loaded.

Comment: try to set it on the html tag, `<img src="bird.png" crossorigin="anonymous"/>`

Comment: https://github.com/ml5js/ml5-library/issues/217#issuecomment-424085565

Answer (score 0):

The problem should persist only if you open index.html directly from file explorer. Because it's using file:// protocol.

When you host it, or use something like Live Server extension in Visual Studio Code (which I highly recommend), everything should work fine because then it will be using http:// protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I do this for my webapp. Works from desktop as well as from web server only using html and javascript. Useful if you dont want to create a localhost on you pc.

1. Remove ALL the cross origin related code you have there. You wont need it.
2. In the img html element remove the bird filename and just make src=‘#’
3. Add a html input type=‘file’  tag and use that to import the image at the click of a button.
4. When you get your image this way, in javascript youll pass the image into a FileReader i.e var reader = FileReader; this is where you convert the image to a data or binary file. CORS accepts data files, but web browsers ‘same origin’ policy may still pose a problem, so...
5. If the image file is small enough use sessionStorage to save the file to the browser storage. If the file is larger than 2 to 5 MB just go the extra mile and save it to IndexedDB. With images its super fast to save and retrieve and worth the extra code.
6. Now retrieve the file from storage and ‘Boom!’ You can use the image anywhere and anyhow you like without cors interference! (Oh yeah, add it to your img tag to see).

Since youre  into machine learning, i’m assuming youre familiar with all these html and javascript api’s. I use it extensively to manipulate images on canvas from the file system which is usually a CORS nightmare!  If youre interested in some code examples let me know.